# What's the better way to store custom logic code blocks configurable for each client in a multitenant architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic

We are running multitenant rails webapp with a lot of clients. We have a kind of workflow module in which after a action has been executed the client need to run different kinds of logic which are completely irrelevant. For example, after that action client A wants to update some details in our app and send out some emails. But client B wants us to run a report after that action is executed. So to tackle this we resorted to storing ruby code in the database with client ID,  and after the action executed we take this code and execute it with eval. I somehow feel this a ugly way of doing things. How can make this better. The logic is completely random for different clients. So what do you guys suggest is better way to handle this?